# Axiom of extensionality in ZF - pointless?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

In every textbook on ZF set theory I come across the Axiom of extensionality, which basically says that if two sets have the same elements, then those two sets are equal:
$$\forall x \forall y (\forall z(z\in x \iff z\in y)\Rightarrow x=y)$$
But why is such statement made to be an axiom? It surely looks like a straightforward definition, because it only relies on the primitive notion of membership, logical connectives and quantifiers. What am I missing here?

Comment: Doesn't *every* formula of ZFC just rely on membership, logical connectives, and quantifiers?

Comment: I thought that was the point, because equality is a new predicate, so it appears on first glance that extentionality defines a predicate in terms of primitives rather than assuming a new axiom about how sets behave in terms of the primitives themselves.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is true that different authors have suggested that extensionality feels closer to a logical axiom than something else, and can be seen as *defining* equality in terms of membership. The question is then whether this is indeed innocuous.

This was considered seriously by Dana Scott, in

> Dana S. Scott. *More on the axiom of extensionality*, in **Essays on the foundations of mathematics**, dedicated to Prof. A. H. Fraenkel on his 70th birthday, Magnes Press, The Hebrew University, Jerusalem, 1961, pp. 115–131. [MR0163838 (29 #1137)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=163838).

Scott considers Zermelo's set theory $\mathsf{Z}$, the standard system of Zermelo-Fraenkel $\mathsf{ZF}$, and their variants $\mathsf{Z}^{\ne}$ and $\mathsf{ZF}^{\ne}$ where extensionality is not assumed. Recall that in $\mathsf{Z}$ we do not assume replacement. (The precise formulation of these theories has some minor technical caveats, see section 1 of the paper.)

Scott shows:

> **1.** There is a relative interpretation of $\mathsf{Z}$ inside $\mathsf{Z}^{\ne}$.
>
> **2.** There is a relative interpretation of $\mathsf{ZF}^{\ne}$ inside $\mathsf{Z}$.

The significance of these results is that of course there is no such interpretation of $\mathsf{ZF}$ within $\mathsf{Z}$, since in fact $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves the consistency of $\mathsf{Z}$. On the other hand, **1** and **2** show that the theories $\mathsf{Z}$, $\mathsf{Z}^{\ne}$, and $\mathsf{ZF}^{\ne}$ are equiconsistent. This proves that the removal of extensionality actually significantly weakens the reach of set theory, and leaves us with a theory of considerably lower consistency strength.

A different issue is whether this would affect mathematical practice, since most of "classical" mathematics does not require replacement anyway (so it can be carried out in $\mathsf{Z}$ and therefore in $\mathsf{Z}^{\ne}$). However, I feel this argument no longer holds water (if it ever did), since big portions of "modern" mathematics do use and need replacement routinely (and so the weaknesses of $\mathsf{ZF}^{\ne}$ with respect to $\mathsf{ZF}$ become now matters of serious concern).

Answer (score 13):

We want to connect the two basic relation symbols, $\in$ and $=$. The axiom of extensionality tells us that if two sets are distinct then there is some witness of this in the universe. Consider the very contrived example $\{\varnothing,\{a\}\}$, with the usual $\in$. The element $a$ is not in the universe of this example, so it cannot internally discern between $\varnothing$ and $\{a\}$.

Comment: Late-late reply, apologies. Would it mean that, by your example, the set $\{ a \}$ will be concluded as a null set, cause object $a$ is ambiguous? Thus the name suggests, extension of membership to equality? $\{a\} = \varnothing$

Comment: No, the idea is that in the structure $(M,\in)$ where $M=\{\varnothing,\{a\}\}$ where $a\neq\varnothing$, it is the case that no object is an element of any other object. In particular, the axiom of extensionality fails there, since $\varnothing$ and $\{a\}$ are distinct objects. The idea, in a nutshell, of the axiom of extensionality is that if two objects are different, then the $\in$ relationship "can see that". Namely, there is something which is an element of the one and not the other. Whereas in our $M$ this isn't the case. The two objects are distinct, but $\in$ fails to see that.

Comment: To recap, the two sets $\{\},\{a\}$ are "seen" distinct by $\in$; even when we are not "aware" of object $a$. Could you please explain what you mean by set membership $\in$, how do you comprehend it?

Comment: The $\in$ membership is the one you know and love. It just means that $x\in y$ if $x$ is an element of $y$. In this case, $\varnothing$ has no elements, and $\{a\}$ has exactly one, $a$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose the set $S$ contains the element $a$ and no other elements.

Suppose the set $T$ contains the element $a$ and no other elements.

Should these sets be equal? If you think so, then you'll have to use extensionality to argue as such: it is the *only* axiom of ZFC that allows you to infer that two sets are equal.