# Is the Axiom of Extensionality equivalent to Leibniz's Law?

Tags: set-theory, predicate-logic

Leibniz's law states that
$$
\forall x\forall y[\forall P(Px \equiv Py) \rightarrow x = y].
$$
This seems awfully similar to the Axiom of Extensionality,
$$
\forall A \forall B[\forall x(x\in A \equiv x \in B)\rightarrow A = B].
$$
Within the framework of set theory, are these logically equivalent? Is Extensionality a strictly stronger statement? Are they even comparable?

Comment: Equivalent in what sense? To some extent, yes, because the only $P$'s you can create in the language of set theory are based off equality and $\in$ anyway. So by induction on the structure of $P$ you should be able to prove something like that. Nevertheless, Extensionality simple states that if two sets are different, then this can be detected via the $\in$ relation within the universe.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing Axiom of Extensionality with a logical formalism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442683/replacing-axiom-of-extensionality-with-a-logical-formalism)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you interpret Leibniz' law.

Leibniz' law follows from Extensionality if we allow predicates of the form "contains $x$" for *arbitrary* $x$. But arbitrary $x$ are not in general definable in any nice way, so these predicates wouldn't be expressibile in any nice way. To give an example of why that's  a problem, consider the predicate "$=x$" - this is expressible in terms of $x$, and serves to distinguish any $y\not=x$ from $x$, since $x$ satisfies the predicate "$=x$" but such a $y$ doesn't satisfy the predicate "$=x$".

So a too-broad interpretation of what predicates can be trivializes Leibniz' law. But it is exactly that kind of broad interpretation which allows extensionality to imply Leibniz' law in general - there can be *indiscernible elements* which are different but can't be distinguished by any formula in whatever fixed system we're working in.

What about the other way around? This also fails, and a good example of this happening in an interesting situation can be provided by certain set theories with urelements. In these set theories, we start with a bunch of "atoms" (or "urelements") in addition to the empty set. These urelements may come with additional structure, algebraic or topological or whatever - for instance, we could start with a *ring* of urelements. In this case we may be able to distinguish urelements from each other in a nice, definable way. But any two urelements have the same elements, namely none.

So really, neither implies the other; the most that can be said is that a too-liberal interpretation of Leibniz' law is trivially true, and hence a fortiori follows from extensionality.

Answer (score 0):

In first order logic **[without](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_extensionality#In_predicate_logic_without_equality)** equality:

$$\forall x(x\in A \equiv x \in B)$$

Does not imply the following and vice versa:

$$\forall y(A\in y \equiv B\in y)$$

**Edit 12.02.2019:**
The provisio without equality is indispensable when we have pairing. When we have equality and pairing then ∀y(A∈y≡B∈y) implies A=B. Just use y={A}. And then A=B implies ∀x(x∈A≡x∈B). I didn't check which other ZFC axioms can do that in the presence of equality.

Comment: It doesn't even imply it *with* equality. The point is that "$\in$" could be interpreted as an arbitrary binary relation: "$A$ and $B$ have the same 'parents'" and "$A$ and $B$ have the same 'children'" are simply unrelated in the absence of further axioms governing the binary relation in question.

Comment: If you have equality and pairing then the second implies the first. See my edit.