# On the relative consistency of the Axiom of Extensionality

Tags: logic, set-theory, math-history

Who proved the relative consistency of the Axiom of Extensionality?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps surprisingly, the situation is a bit complicated!

Let's start with a pair of results, one positive and one negative, from the same paper. [Scott showed](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/437873/28111) that $\mathsf{Z-Ext}$ is equiconsistent with $\mathsf{Z}$, but $\mathsf{ZF-Ext}$ is in fact equiconsistent with ... $\mathsf{Z}$ again! So adding extensionality to $\mathsf{ZF-Ext}$ results in a *huge* increase in consistency strength, but adding it to $\mathsf{Z-Ext}$ doesn't change consistency strength at all.

Focusing on the $\mathsf{ZF}$-flavored situation, Scott's result relies on the exact way the $\mathsf{ZF}$ axioms are posed; specifically, it assumes that we're using **replacement** instead of **collection**. If we use collection instead, we *do* get equiconsistency: $\mathsf{ZF_{coll}-Ext}$ is equiconsistent with $\mathsf{ZF}$, where $\mathsf{ZF_{coll}}$ is $\mathsf{ZF}$ with the collection scheme instead of the replacement scheme. In fact, full $\mathsf{ZF}$ can be "embedded" into even *intuitionistic* $\mathsf{ZF_{coll}-Ext}$ in a precise sense; this was shown by [Friedman](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2272068). So between the Scott and Friedman results it's clear that there is a high degree of detail-sensitivity here.

*Incidentally, note that the replacement/collection issue is also crucial in making sense of "$\mathsf{ZF(C)}$ without powerset" - see [Gitman/Hamkins/Johnstone](https://arxiv.org/abs/1110.2430).*

Separately, Gandy gave equiconsistency proofs for extensionality over non-extensional versions of [simple type theory](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2268484?seq=1#metadata_info_tab_contents) and [NBG](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/2963897.pdf). Specker's proof that $\mathsf{NF+AC}$ is inconsistent, in light of the low consistency strength of $\mathsf{NFU+AC}$, can be construed as another negative observation. And finally, [Enayat mentions](https://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2005-April/008906.html) a paper of Robinson as being relevant, but I can't get a hold of it at the moment.

Comment: Scott's result is by far the least talked about and most surprising of all the relative consistency results of subtheories of ZF.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I agree, at least for theories above/around Z. I think Mathias has some deeply surprising results lower down but it's been a while.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I have studied, and at points made use of, all the papers you mention, except the one by Robinson. They did not come to my mind. 

If I recall correctly, Scott shows that ZF* = ZF minus extensionality, and with = in the replacement scheme replaced by co-extensionality, interprets ZF, but ZF^ = ZF (with ordinary replacement) minus extensionality does not interpres ZF. So, at any rate, Scott's result qualifies as a relative consistency result.  

As does the work by Gandhi, if I remember correctly.